# Adding a data file to existing sql server database taking too long

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I am trying to add file using below

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [foo] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'foo_1', FILENAME = N'D:\Data10\Data\foo10.ndf' , SIZE = 102400000KB , FILEGROWTH = 0) TO FILEGROUP [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Actually i have to add 2 TB file to this 3 TB disk, but trying to add in chunks of 100 GB

But it seems to be running for past 30 mins

HOw can i improve this?

Update:

The Query above completed in 40 mins. The wait was ASYNC_IO_COMPLETION

Also, this database is 24*7 and has DB mirroring configured.

Now, i am trying to increase in 50 GB chunks using below

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [foo] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'foo_10', SIZE = 153600000KB )
GO
```

Above seems to be running for past 10 mins with wait (183043ms)PREEMPTIVE_OS_WRITEFILEGATHER

Comment: Is [instant file initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-instant-file-initialization) enabled?

Comment: Make sure the SQL Server service account has to perform volume maintenance task Windows privilege.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik yes sir

Comment: While you're adding a file, what are you waiting on? Can you run sp_WhoIsActive and get waits?

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik, i just updated the question, thanks

Comment: Either you don't have IFI enabled or you're using TDE or something. If nothing is blocking that session and your disk has enough space, it shouldn't be waiting on that.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik, exactly thats what i thought. IFI enabled and no TDE. Not sure why then

Comment: Please pardon my mathematical error - answer removed. Sigh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling something is iffy about your setup here.

If you run the following script:

```
DBCC TRACEON(3004, 3605, -1);
GO

CREATE DATABASE Crap;
GO

EXEC sys.sp_readerrorlog;
GO

DROP DATABASE Crap;
GO
```

You should see this in the error log:

[image: NUTS]

In other words, only the transaction log needs to be zeroed out. The data file should skip this.

I can run this commands and have it finish instantly as well:

```
ALTER DATABASE Crap
    ADD FILE ( NAME = N'Crap_1', FILENAME = N'F:\SQL\Data\Crap_1.ndf', SIZE = 102400000KB, FILEGROWTH = 0 )
    TO FILEGROUP [PRIMARY];
GO
```

If you're on a new enough version of SQL Server (as your question >implies), you can see if this query helps:

```
SELECT servicename, instant_file_initialization_enabled
FROM   sys.dm_server_services;
```

If that doesn't work, you'll have to go back in time and use `whoami` to [determine that](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2014/03/12/using-whoami-to-check-for-instant-file-initialization.aspx).

Keep in mind that your server needs to be restarted to enable IFI, so if you just added the priv, or you added it and never restarted SQL, it won't be in effect.

> Also, this database is 24*7 and has DB mirroring configured

If this is sync mirroring, perhaps IFI isn't enabled on the parter? Have you checked to see what's up over there?

Comment: Thanks erik, i will check on that. However now the database in question has mirroring suspended after adding 150 GB. Trying to resume not working. Any idea how to get this going?

Comment: Question: Does your partner server have enough space to accommodate the file expansion? @BeginnerDBA

Comment: @SeanGallardy-Microsoft-- yes space is there, i forgot to add one folder. Now that is synchronizing state

Comment: Thanks Erik, i will mark this as answered as it seems the account added on partner for IFI did not had a restart of SQL. But one strange thing, just now, that 100 GB growth completed in 2 mins? Got surprised. what just happened?

Comment: @BeginnerDBA wow, not sure off hand. Glad it worked though. 100GB can be a long wait.